# Combining all objects in an array into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects arr and I want to combine all of the objects in the array into one. There also are repetitive keys in the objects. Is there a way I can do this? Any help would be great.

```
var arr = [{ a: 1, a: 2 },
{ c: 1, d: 2 },
{ e: 14, f: 20 }];
```

The output I want is:

```
var arr = [{ a: 1, 
             a1: 2, 
             c: 1, 
             d: 2, 
             e: 14, 
             f: 20 }];
```

Comment: 2 minutes solution: https://jsfiddle.net/osp5fawq/

Comment: Do you mean that your output is supposed to have `a`, and `b`, and not `a`, and `a`, right?

Comment: I have multiple keys that are the same and want to rename them if there are duplicates.

Comment: @KevBot yes that is what I want in the output, basically

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all the keys are unique and you don't want to check, use `reduce`

```
var combinedKeys = arr.reduce(function(a, item) {
    Object.keys(item).map(function(key) {
        a[key] = item[key];
    });

    return a;
}, {});

var singleArrayOfCombinedKeys = [combinedKeys]; //[Object  a: 1b: 2c: 1d: 2e: 14f: 20__proto__: Object]
```

Comment: This is a great answer, So how would I approach this issue if I do have keys that are not unique but still want them included.

Comment: @JacobBrauchler -- Depends on the outcome you want - are you looking to sum the numbers up?

Comment: no I I do not want to sum them up I want the object to look like the output in my question, I was just using the numbers as an example.

Comment: @JacobBrauchler -- Well if you have the same key twice, it can't be in the structure you want. Keys have to be unique. You can combine the values, or create an array of values.

Comment: is there a way that if it isn't unique you just rename it?

Comment: @JacobBrauchler - Rename it to what?

Comment: so say I had two keys named a just make the second one a1 or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply iterate through the array using `for` loop and assign all properties of each item to the combined object:

```js
var arr = [{ a: 1, b: 2 },
{ c: 1, d: 2 },
{ e: 14, f: 20 }];

var combinedObj = {};

for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
{
  var item = arr[i];
  for(var key in item )
  {
    combinedObj[key] = item[key];
  }//for()
}//for

console.log( combinedObj );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce()` and `Object.assign()`

```js
var arr = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { c: 1, d: 2 }, { e: 14, f: 20 }];

var result  = [arr.reduce((r, o) => Object.assign(r, o), {})];
console.log(result)
```